# Convert multilines to single line with SED

Tags: shell-script, sed

I need additional help, based on similar question I have located here: [Convert multilines to single line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218403/convert-multilines-to-single-line/218453#218453)

Current SED example

```
(sed  -e'y/)},={/(((((/' \
  -e's/-\([^(I]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)[( ]*/- \2 -\1/;=' |
paste -d- - - |
sort  -t- -nk3,3 -nk1,1 |
sed   -e's/^[^-]*-//;:n' -e'h;$!N' \
  -e's/\(-\([^-]*-\).*[^ ]\) *\n\([^-]*-\)\{2\}\2/\1 - \3/;tn' \
  -ex\;:t -e's/\(\([^-]*-\)[^/]*\) - *\2/\1,/;tt'   -e'p;g;D' ) \
< in.txt > out.txt
```

Following multiline log

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - {   562} START Web 
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103[123.125.71.103], ID=562 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} START POP3 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=563 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   563) USER test.mail@test.me 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=563 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} START POP3 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=564 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   564) USER test.mail@test.me 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=564 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ID=562 
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - {   562} END Web
```

Is converted to

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - 562 - START Web, Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] - 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended., END Web
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - 563 - START POP3, Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], USER test.mail@test.me, POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended., END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - 564 - START POP3, Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], USER test.mail@test.me, POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended., END POP3
```

I would like to modify SED to include also follwoing logs where IDs are in square brackets (example: `[ 667]`).

Log example

```
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Starting delivery thread, ID=667
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - {   667} START Delivery
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Active delivery threads (ID=667 start): 0
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Delivering to test.mail@test.com
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Forwarding mail...
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Forwarding message to 1 address(es)
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Delivery thread, ID=667, terminated after running for 0.031 seconds.
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - {   667} END Delivery
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Active delivery threads (ID=667 end): 0
```

Second question I have is how should I ignore logs where there is no ID.
This is not so critical, but would be nice to filter out.

For example:

```
6/13/2015 2:43:24 AM - Exended logging
6/13/2015 2:43:24 AM - Setting msgSizeLimit 15
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only the first `sed` which needs modifying to handle all of the possibilities you list here. Specifically, rather than handling all possibilities in a single regexp, instead you'll need to address two different kinds of lines separately - the kind on which the *`ID`* immediately follows the first `-` dash on a line, and the other kind on which it is found labeled as *`ID=`* somewhere else.

```
(   sed -e= -e's/- [({[] *\([0-9]*\) *[])}]/- \1 -/;t' \
            -e's/-\(.*[^, ]\)[, ]*ID=\([0-9]*\)[, ]\{0,1\}/- \2 -\1/' |
    paste   -d- - - |
    sort    -t- -nk3,3 -nk1,1 |
    sed     -e's/^[^-]*-//;:n' -e'h;$!N' \
            -e's/\(-\([^-]*-\).*[^ ]\) *\n\([^-]*-\)\{2\}\2/\1 - \3/;tn' \
            -ex\;:t -e's/\(\([^-]*-\)[^/]*\)- *\2/\1:::/;tt'   -e'p;g;D'
) <in >out
```

Here it is a second time, but written with `-E`xtended regular expression syntax. This will work at least with BSD/GNU/AST `sed`s:

```
(   sed -Ee= -e's/- [({[] *([0-9]+) *[])}]/- \1 -/;t' \
             -e's/-(.*[^, ])[, ]*ID=([0-9]+)[, ]?/- \2 -\1/' |
    paste    -d- - - |
    sort     -t- -nk3,3 -nk1,1 |
    sed      -Ee's/^[^-]*-//;:n' -e'h;$!N' \
             -e's/(-([^-]+-).*[^ ]) *\n([^-]+-){2}\2/\1 - \3/;tn' \
             -ex\;:t -e's/(([^-]+-)[^/]*)- *\2/\1:::/;tt' -e'p;g;D'
) <in >out
```

Now I tested that on a concatenation of all of your log data:

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - {   562} START Web
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103[123.125.71.103], ID=562
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} START POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=563
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   563) USER test.mail@test.me
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=563
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} START POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=564
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   564) USER test.mail@test.me
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=564
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ID=562
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - {   562} END Web
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Starting delivery thread, ID=667
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - {   667} START Delivery
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Active delivery threads (ID=667 start): 0
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Delivering to test.mail@test.com
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Forwarding mail...
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - [   667] Forwarding message to 1 address(es)
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Delivery thread, ID=667, terminated after running for 0.031 seconds.
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - {   667} END Delivery
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - Active delivery threads (ID=667 end): 0
```

And my results were:

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - 562 - START Web ::: Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103[123.125.71.103] - 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ::: END Web
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - 563 - START POP3 ::: Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ::: USER test.mail@test.me ::: POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ::: END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - 564 - START POP3 ::: Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ::: USER test.mail@test.me ::: POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ::: END POP3
6/13/2015 2:15:09 AM - 667 - Starting delivery thread ::: START Delivery ::: Active delivery threads (start): 0 ::: Delivering to test.mail@test.com ::: Forwarding mail... ::: Forwarding message to 1 address(es) ::: Delivery thread terminated after running for 0.031 seconds. ::: END Delivery ::: Active delivery threads (end): 0
```

Comment: You are fantastcic. Any recommendation where should I look for good SED, AWK,... literature.

Comment: Tested on real data and working as expected. Thanks once again.

Comment: @mmesojedec - well, when I first started `sed`ding I followed [the Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) pretty thoroughly. I sometimes look at it now and find little mistakes here and there, but it's still pretty good. It's definitely the best launching point of which I know. But the only real way to learn how is to do: so how I learn - how I continue to learn - is just to take apart interesting statements and try to alter their behavior. Most important are two fundamentals: 1. `l`ook. It's the command the will teach you `sed`. And 2. it's all cause and effect - newton's law stuff.

Comment: Some additional question: Is there any way to use comma and separate it only with this. For example I'm seeing in some logs different data and there "-" separator is used -> Like this: 6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - 562 - START Web, Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] - 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended., END Web         I would like to replace "-" in this example with comma:                              "[123.125.71.103] - 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web " with "[123.125.71.103], 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM, Web"

Comment: @mmesojedec - yes. At the very end there, replace `p` with `s/ -/,/gp`. Or if you still want the dashes for the id but not for the times, replace the `p` w/ `s| -\([^/-]*/\)|,\1|g;p`.